# Can't Initialize Google Play Services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

This is my first time trying to use Google Play Services.

I added the libraries "google-play-services-lib" and "BaseGameUtils". I changed my class to extends "BaseGameActivity"

Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    Button  skipBut;
    View signInBut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        skipBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.justPlay);
        signInBut = (View) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        skipBut.setOnClickListener(this); 
        signInBut.setOnClickListener(this);            

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button){
            beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        }
        else if(view.getId() == R.id.justPlay){
            // play without sign in .... code ....
        }
    }

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

But my Apps is crashing down. I can't find why. 
**Note:** I also added the app ID to the Manifest and to the strings (as app_id).

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.*****id****"
           android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Here is the logCat :

```
09-08 14:57:19.500: W/ActivityThread(18213): Application com.cdev.colormatch is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-08 14:57:19.520: I/System.out(18213): Sending WAIT chunk
09-08 14:57:19.540: I/dalvikvm(18213): Debugger is active
09-08 14:57:19.720: I/System.out(18213): Debugger has connected
09-08 14:57:19.725: I/System.out(18213): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-08 14:57:19.925: I/System.out(18213): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-08 14:57:20.125: I/System.out(18213): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-08 14:57:20.325: I/System.out(18213): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-08 14:57:20.525: I/System.out(18213): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-08 14:57:20.725: I/System.out(18213): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-08 14:57:20.925: I/System.out(18213): waiting for debugger to settle...
09-08 14:57:21.125: I/System.out(18213): debugger has settled (1465)
09-08 14:57:21.505: W/PopupManager(18213): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
09-08 14:57:22.225: D/dalvikvm(18213): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
```

**Update**

I have tried using game helper without extending to GameBaseActivity ( as explained in https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#using_gamehelper_without_basegameactivity)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    Button  skipBut;
    View signInBut;

    GameHelper mHelper;

    boolean mExplicitSignOut = false;
    boolean mInSignInFlow = false;
    GoogleApiClient mClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



        skipBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.justPlay);
        signInBut = (View) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        skipBut.setOnClickListener(this); 
          signInBut.setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);
            builder.addApi(Games.API)
                   .addApi(Plus.API)
                   .addApi(AppStateManager.API)
                   .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                   .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                   .addScope(AppStateManager.SCOPE_APP_STATE);
            mClient = builder.build();

            mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);


            GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                    // handle sign-in succeess
                }
                @Override
                public void onSignInFailed() {
                    // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
                }

            };
            mHelper.setup(listener);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button){
            mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        }
        else if(view.getId() == R.id.justPlay){
            // skipp sign in
        }
    }
}
```

But still crashes down :(

Comment: This may be of some use : https://github.com/marmalade/s3eGooglePlayGames/blob/master/source/android/GameHelper.java

Comment: This is the GameHelper class which I am using as a library. What are you trying to point me ? @2Dee

Comment: The logcat you specify does not contain any errors, so it's a bit difficult to determine what the problem might be. Update the logcat with a copy that includes the error (i.e. where the app crashes) - it will be prefixed with an `E`.

Comment: Also note that when you extend `BaseGameActivity`, sign-in will be called automatically in `onStart`, so your buttons won't work as expected. If you want to use those buttons, you can either set `mConnectOnStart=false` in `onCreate` or you should go without extending `GameBaseActivity`. Still doesn't answer your question, but just a heads up.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration)

you will need to add some java code to your onCreate() also try to follow the steps one by one in the right column

```
 // Java code required.
 // testDevices and loadAdOnCreate attributes are
 // no longer available.
 AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
.build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Am I wrong or this link is for the instruction of applying banner and/or ads ? @user1283633